# Database models and migrations explanation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, sqlite

I would like to confirm that I understand how database models and migrations work from someone who knows this subject better than myself.

Model: How the database is structured and how the data is organized. Their relationship to other tables and what goes in every single column.

Migration: The actual creation of the data tables?

For some reason, I've googled this and can't get a simple explanation on this answer. If the model creates the database structure, why would I even need a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! A model isn't just the "creation of the database structure" though-- the model is how the ruby code sees the database structure. It's really another representation of the database structure that rails can use to pass around data that it gets from the database. The reason that you put all of the information about the table into the model is so that ruby can use that information to automatically get rows out of the database and put them into those model objects.

A migration, on the other hand, changes the database from one schema to another. Every time you create a new model, a new migration will be created to create the table that corresponds to the model. You also have to create a new migration whenever you want to change a model (and the table that corresponds to it).

Comment: so the migration does the actual creating of the tables? The model just gives the instructions on how it will be created?

Comment: More or less. I'd probably say: the migration is created based on the model.

Comment: So this explains why when one change is made to a model a migration needs to occur right?

Comment: Exactly! The model and the database structure need to be kept in sync, and the migrations are what do it.

Comment: Changes to the model do not necessarily require a migration unless the **schema** changes as well. For example, adding helper methods does not require a migration.

Comment: @Substantial are helper methods just functions that enclose a bunch of code. In other words instead of having to keep writing the same code we can just invoke the function?

Comment: Pretty much. Suppose your database has separate columns for first and last name, but you want to present a full name. Instead of writing `@obj.first_name + @obj.last_name` everywhere in your app, define a `full_name` helper method in the model that returns first name + last name; use it like `@obj.full_name`. No migration needed since the DB structure wasn't modified, just the presentation.